# Remove First Forward Slash from IMG SRC

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, src

I have an image tag..

```
<img src="/folder1/folder2/image.jpg">
```

I need to, using javascript / query remove the first forward slash from the src tag to make the image tag like this.

```
<img src="folder1/folder2/image.jpg">
```

I would like to do this for any image on the page.

Any thoughts?

Justin

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tested and works:

```
$('img').each(
    function(){
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        if (src.indexOf('/') === 0){
            this.src = src.replace('/','');
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5jF4B/).

As per nnnnn's suggestion, in comments below, an alternative solution using `substring()`:

```
$('img').each(
    function(){
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        if (src.indexOf('/') === 0){
            this.src = src.substring(1);
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5jF4B/1/).

Note that I'm using:

```
var src = $(this).attr('src');
```

because I want the actual contents of the attribute, rather than the browser's evaluated interpretation of that attribute (for example with `src="/folder1/folder2/image.jpg"` on jsFiddle `this.src` returns `http://fiddle.jshell.net/folder1/folder2/image.jpg`).

Comment: Or instead of `replace()`, perhaps `this.src = this.src.substr(1);`

Comment: Actually now that I've thought about it, you could lose the if test checking the indexOf() and just say `this.src = this.src.replace(/^\//,"");`

Comment: Ah, you see, now we're in *regex*, and...that's where I *really* start to struggle...perhaps post an answer offering that solution? Ideally with an explanation for idiots (just so's I can understand...). =)

Comment: No, you deserve the points, both for getting in first and more importantly for dealing with the src as attribute issue which I wouldn't have thought of. The explanation on `/^\//` is that ^ means the beginning of the string, in this case followed by a forward slash (which needs to be escaped with a backslash) - if there is a forward slash as the first character it'll be replaced, otherwise nothing will happen.